# Make settimeout different depending on certain factors

Tags: javascript, cookies, refresh, settimeout

I'm trying to refresh a page, and every time I refresh the page, I want to roll a random number. If it's zero I want the page to wait 5 seconds before refreshing again. If it's one I want the page to wait 1 second before refreshing again? However, with my code, the page either refreshes after 1 second every single time, or it refreshes after 5 seconds every single time. What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Please use the codes that I have, and point out what I did wrong in my code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        google.com
// @namespace   John Galt
// @description Basic Google Hello
// @match       *^https://www.google.com/$*
// @version     1
// @require     https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @run-at document-end
// ==/UserScript==

//*****************************************START OF SET_TIMEOUT
(function ($) {
  'use strict';
  var interval;
  if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0) { interval = 1000; }
  else { interval = 5000; }
  if (window == window.top) {
    var body = $('body').empty();
    var myframe = $('<iframe>')
      .attr({ src: location.href })
      .css({ height: '95vh', width: '100%' })
      .appendTo(body)
      .on('load', function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
          myframe.attr({ src: location.href });
        }, interval);
      });
  }
})(jQuery);
//*****************************************END OF SET_TIMEOUT
```

Comment: Why do you need cookies here? on page reload generate a random number and decide the interval.

Comment: @MunimMunna Well, that was just an example. In reality, I need to check a variable each time the page refreshes. Depending on the variable, the page needs to wait either 1 or 5 seconds before refreshing again. In order to remember what that variable is, I needed to use cookies.

Comment: `getCookie(cookieName)+addTo` why are you adding? because of this, the value of cookie goes like this `""`, `"true"`, `"truetrue"`, `"truetruetrue"` ....

Comment: @MunimMunna Okay, instead of addToCookie, I wrote a new function called setCookie, but it still didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Now it should reload after every 5s once the cookie is set, because you never set the cookie to false.

Comment: @MunimMunna I'm using the deleteCookie function to delete the cookie once it's set to 5 seconds though, so on the next refresh it could be 1 or 5 seconds.

Comment: @MunimMunna Okay. Let's remove cookies completely from this, and just use regular random number on each page refresh. It still refreshes either 1 second every single time, or 5 seconds every single time.

Comment: No I understood what you are doing, you need to generate the random number inside `<iframe>` `load` event. Only that load event executes when the `iframe` reloads.

Comment: @MunimMunna I edited the code, and tried putting it inside, but it's still not working. Did I put it in the wrong place? Can you write the code in an answer format, and I'll accept your answer and you'll get 10 points? Thanks.

Comment: You are going in right direction, move that code inside load event, before `setTimeout`. I will answer if I get time, but hope you can do it before that. If you get time see [basic debugging](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp), it may help you undertsnad better how you code is working.